# Is there a function in string that extracts a specific substring from all occurences of a delimiter?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string for example that has multiple strings within it that contain tokens that must be extracted while also removing duplicates

```
{..}P1, {..}P2, {..}P3, {..}P3
{..}P4, {..}P1, {..}P6, {..}P5
```

Is there a built in string function (or one that can be made) that can be used to create this tokens?:

```
P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6
```

The P tokens will always immediately follow an ending curly brace with no space in between. How can I achieve the result?

Comment: Use a `Regex` pattern to extract and LINQ to process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant your string (I used `src`) has multiple lines within it, this should work:

```
var pRE = new Regex(@"(?<=})[^,\r\n]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var ans = String.Join(", ", pRE.Matches(src).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct());
```

I did not sort the Px however.

Here is a non-RE based version using an extension method I have `UpTo` which takes an array of stopper characters and returns the string up to the first occurrence, or the whole string if none occur.

```
var ans = src.Split('}').Skip(1).Select(s => s.UpTo(',', '\r', '\n')).Distinct();
```

Here is the extension:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string UpTo(this string s, params char[] stopChars) {
        var stopPos = s.IndexOfAny(stopChars);
        return (stopPos >= 0) ? s.Substring(0, stopPos) : s;
    }    
    public static T MinOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, T defval = default) => src.DefaultIfEmpty(defval).Min();
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Would you be able to implement this without regex? @NetMage

Comment: @Shylif, can you elaborate reasons not to use regular expression? This feels like an assignment. Do you really want community to solve it for you??

Comment: It's not an assignment I just would like to have saw another solution to compare speed and memory efficiency.

Comment: @Shylif I added a non-RE solution using LINQ and Split.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use regex to solve your problem. But if you want to do it without using regex then you can use split('}') on your string to create a collection of substrings, then take all substrings starting with P followed by a number, then sort the result and join your collection into a new string.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there can be if you make an extension method out of this solution, which uses a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and no regular expressions.

Without knowing all of your constraints, this may not be 100% correct, but it *does* yield the correct output you are looking for. You can add states and constraints to this if necessary.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = @"        {..}P1, {.sdfsdfsdf.}P2, {.sdfsdfsdf.}P3, {..}P3
    {..}P4, {..}P1, {..}P8886, {..}P5";

        var items = Extractinator(input).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> Extractinator(string source)
    {
        var state = States.Extraneous;
        string item = "";
        foreach (var c in source)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case States.Extraneous:
                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case '{':
                            state = States.InsideBrackets;
                            break;
                    }
                    continue;
                case States.InsideBrackets:
                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case '}':
                            state = States.BuildingItem;
                            break;
                    }
                    continue;
                case States.BuildingItem:
                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case char _ when char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsLetter(c):
                            item += c;
                            break;
                        default:
                            yield return item;
                            item = "";
                            state = States.Extraneous;
                            break;
                    }
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (item != "")
            yield return item;
    }

    enum States
    {
        Extraneous,
        InsideBrackets,
        BuildingItem,
    }
}
```

I gummed up the input just to make it a little more realistic. I also used `switch` rather than `if`/`else` as that's a "classic" way to do it that allows you to add in new rules if necessary. For example, if the comma `,` is really the signal to move to extraneous text, then in `case States.BuildingItem` you might want to replace `case char _ when char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsLetter(c):` with `case char _ when c != ',':`.

The key to state machines like this is buffering up partial results, yielding/doing something with the results when complete, and knowing when to switch states.